# How to autocomplete a bash commandline with file paths?

Tags: linux, bash, autocomplete

## Context

I am creating a shell program which is a command line tool. I want to create my own auto-completion for this tool.

I want to do two different things (maybe should I post two questions):

- for the options `--install` and `-i`, I want to auto-complete on file paths, like the `ls` command do.
- for the options `--unit-test` and `-t`, I want to auto-complete on file paths from a particular directory which I can get running `my_app --directory`.

**`my_app_autocomplete` file**

```
__my_app_autocomplete()
{
    local cur prev opts
    COMPREPLY=()
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}"
    opts="--help -h --install -i --run -r --rebuild -rb --show-running-containers -ps --stop -s --remove -rm --logs -l --bash -b --sass -css --unit-tests -t"
    containers="nginx php mysql mongo node"
    sass="watch"

    # By default, autocomplete with options
    if [[ ${prev} == my_app ]] ; then
        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${opts}" -- ${cur}) )
        return 0
    fi
    # By default, autocomplete with options
    if [[ ${cur} == -* ]] ; then
        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${opts}" -- ${cur}) )
        return 0
    fi
    # For --install and -i options, autocomplete with folder
    if [ ${prev} == --install ] || [ ${prev} == -i ] ; then
        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -d -- ${cur}) )
        return 0
    fi
    # For --stop --remove --logs and --bash, autocomplete with containers
    if [ ${prev} == --stop ] || [ ${prev} == -s ] || [ ${prev} == --remove ] || [ ${prev} == -rm ] || [ ${prev} == --logs ] || [ ${prev} == -l ] || [ ${prev} == --bash ] || [ ${prev} == -b ] ; then
        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${containers}" -- ${cur}) )
        return 0
    fi
    # For --sass and -css, complete with sass options
    if [ ${prev} == --sass ] || [ ${prev} == -css ] ; then
        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${sass}" -- ${cur}) )
        return 0
    fi
    # For --unit-tests and -t, complete with relative to my_app folder paths
    if [ ${prev} == --unit-tests ] || [ ${prev} == -t ] ; then
        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -d -- ${cur}) )
        return 0
    fi
}
complete -F __my_app_autocomplete my_app
```

## Problem

I struggle on a particular point: auto-complete file paths.

I don't understand `compgen` options and how to do things with it. Maybe I could try to run a subcommand but I don't know the syntax and I can't find any useful information except [man of bash - Programmable completion builtins](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html) which does not give much information about `compgen`.

In this case, when I do:

```
user@computer:~$ my_app --install D[TAB][TAB]
```

I would like:

```
user@computer:~$ my_app --install Documents/
```

I obtain:

```
user@computer:~$ myapp --install Documents
```

with a blank space at the end of the line, which is a problem because I have to erase it and add a `/` to be able to redo `[TAB][TAB]` to auto-complete for sub-directories.

## Investigations

### -o nospace

With the option `-o nospace` applied on `complete` as:

```
complete -o nospace -F __my_app_autocomplete my_app
```

the behavior is:

```
user@computer:~$ myapp --i[TAB][TAB]
user@computer:~$ myapp --install
```

without space.

```
user@computer:~$ myapp --install D[TAB][TAB]
user@computer:~$ myapp --install Documents
```

without space.

**Problems:**

- It removes spaces for all options, forcing me to manually add a space after those that aren't file paths (like `--install`)
- I have to add `/` to navigate into sub directories

### -o filenames

With the option `-o filenames` applied on `complete` as:

```
complete -o filenames -F __my_app_autocomplete my_app
```

the behavior is:

```
user@computer:~$ myapp --i[TAB][TAB]
user@computer:~$ myapp --install
```

with a space

```
user@computer:~$ myapp --install D[TAB][TAB]
user@computer:~$ myapp --install Documents/
```

with a `/` and without space if it's a directory

```
user@computer:~$ myapp --install f[TAB][TAB]
user@computer:~$ myapp --install file
```

with a space if it's a file

It seems to set paths only for completion not defined in an list of words, so it does not affect other completions, I think it's the first part of what I need.

### From a particular directory

I will open another question to avoid mixing things: [How to autocomplete a bash commandline with file paths from a specific directory without displaying this directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44453510/how-to-autocomplete-a-bash-commandline-with-file-paths-from-a-specific-directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## To auto complete file paths

Substitute

```
complete -F __my_app_autocomplete my_app
```

with

```
complete -o filenames -F __my_app_autocomplete my_app
```

Here you can find all the compgen options explained:

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html

Comment: If you read carefully my question, you can see there is a link to this documentation... Thanks, the `-o filenames` solved the first part of my problem, what about the second part: from a particular folder?

Comment: I split my question to avoid mixing things: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44453510/how-to-autocomplete-a-bash-commandline-with-file-paths-from-a-specific-directory Thank you for your help!