# Custom Bash Autocomplete with File Path Completion

Tags: bash, macos, bash-completion

I'm working on bash auto-completion for a project I'm the maintainer of.  You can [find the script here](https://github.com/astorm/pestle/blob/master/pestle-autocomplete.sh).  I've cobbled this together with some hacking on my own, and with the help of some contributors who understand that completion APIs better than I do.

What we have works great -- with one exception.  We can manage a completion like like this

```
//type
pestle.phar som[TAB]

//completes to 
pestle.phar some-command-name
```

However, once we're here we *lose* file path/name completion that's a part of the stock bash shell.  That is, working off the previous example, if a user types

```
//type
pestle.phar some-command-name /va[TAB]
```

we'd like it to complete to

```
//completes to the following, because var exists
pestle.phar some-command-name /var
```

Is there a way to just tell the `complete` command something like

> Hey, in addition to everything we're telling you to do with our custom bash function, also keep your normal file path completion

If not, is there there some known science/boilerplate to reimplementing the file path completion in your own custom base completion functions?

Some [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44441249/how-to-autocomplete-a-bash-commandline-with-file-paths) and [the docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html) *seem* to indicate that the `-o filenames` or `-o bashdefault` options should take care of this -- but it doesn't seem to be working on OS X 10.11.  I'm not sure if I misunderstand `-o`, or if the code in my completion files somehow overrides the `-o` behavior, or if OS X is doing it's *I'm only a mostly well behaved unix* thing.

Also -- if it's not obvious -- this **is** my first deep bash completion rodeo.  If I've said something seemingly dumb/naive above please let me know.  I may be looking for a fish right now, but I'd like to learn **to** fish in the bash completion river myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think `-o default` (without `-o filenames`) should work for you. According to the manual:

> - **bashdefault**
>     Perform the rest of the *default bash completions* if the compspec generates no matches.
> - **default**
>     Use *readline's default filename completion* if the compspec generates no matches.
> - **filenames**
>     Tell  readline  that the compspec generates filenames, so it can perform any filename-specific processing (like adding a slash to directory
>     names, quoting special characters, or suppressing trailing spaces).  Intended to be used with shell functions.

(Also see ['complete -d -o default cd' issue](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2011-07/msg00069.html) for the difference between `-o default` and `-o bashdefault`.)

Comment: Nice!  Thank you @whjm, that did the trick **and** taught me that bash autocomplete and readline auto complete are two different things.